# How to rebind in Laravel’s container?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request, ioc-container

I’m trying to add functionality similar to the user resolver in Laravel’s `Request` class.

I have a SaaS application. I’ve created a middleware class to look at the request host and fetch the corresponding account based on the domain. It looks like this:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $host = $request->getHost();

    $domain = Domain::whereName($host)->firstOrFail();

    return $next($request);
}
```

I’ve extended the `Request` class with one in my application, and updated the reference in **public/index.php** to use this new class. I’ve also added three new methods:

```php
public function account()
{
    return call_user_func($this->getAccountResolver());
}

public function getAccountResolver()
{
    return $this->accountResolver ?: function () {};
}

public function setAccountResolver(Closure $callback)
{
    $this->accountResolver = $callback;

    return $this;
}
```

The idea is, I want to be able to get the account from the request the same way I can get the currently logged-in user:

```php
$user = $request->user();
$account = $request->account(); // My new method
```

I had a look in the Laravel codebase and they seem to use rebinding to add the user resolver. From the `AuthServiceProvider` class:

```php
$this->app->rebinding('request', function ($app, $request) {
    $request->setUserResolver(function () use ($app) {
        return $app['auth']->user();
    });
});
```

So I replicated this in my middleware method:

```php
$this->app->rebinding('request', function ($app, $request) use ($domain) {
    $request->setAccountResolver(function () use ($app, $domain) {
        return $domain->account; // Domain belongs to an Account
    });
});
```

But this doesn’t seem to get triggered. If I run `dd($request)` in the middleware I can see the `$accountResolver` property is an instance of a `Closure` (my callback), but when I `dd($request)` *after* the middleware class (say a controller action), the `$accountResolver` method is back to being `null`.

How can I get my account resolver to persist after my middleware, so that I can call `$request->account()` and get an `Account` instance throughout my application?

Comment: >So I replicated this in my middleware method.

Does this mean you run `$this->app` in your middleware class? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I used `app()` instead of `$this->app`.

Comment: But since you're actually doing a re`bind`ing, try doing it in a `ServiceProvider`. Use the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` `register()` method to test your rebinding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this in another project after Googling this issue and ironically ending up on my own question!

In my **AppServiceProvider**’s `register()` method I have this code:

```
$this->app->rebinding('request', function ($app, $request) {
    $request->setUserResolver(function () {
        // Customer user resolving logic here
    });
}
```

And in my controllers, if I type-hint the `Request` class…

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //
}
```

…then any calls to `$request->user()` gets the user resolved using my custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `app('auth')->resolveUsersUsing(fn () => $domain->account);` on middleware handle method.